# SSRS Do not include Null in bar chart

Tags: reporting-services, graph, null

I have a table like so:

[image]

The graph is including the CalLocation row value = NULL

[image]

Is there a way to not include the CalcLocation = to Null on the graph in SSRS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a **Filter** to the chart to exclude the NULL values for the CalcLocation field.

Go to Chart Properties' **Filter** tab.

For the expression, use the **ISNOTHING** function to check if the field is NULL and return **0** if it is and **1** if it is not null.

```
=IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!CalcLocation.Value), 0, 1)
```

Set the Type to **Integer**, the Operator to **=** and the Value to **1**.

The expression will return a 0 if the field is NULL and the filter only allows for records that have a 1.

[image]